# Trying to get property 'nombre' of non-object (View:

Tags: php

Tengo este array

```
$portafolios =[['nombre' => 'carlos'],['nombre','ana']];
```

cuando lo recibo en la vista me muestra esto con var_dump($portafolios)

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["nombre"]=> string(6) "carlos" } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "nombre" [1]=> string(3) "ana" } }

@foreach ($portafolios as $portafolio)
       {{ $portafolio->nombre }}
    @endforeach
```

me marca este error:

> **Trying to get property 'nombre' of non-object (View: C:\laragon\www\laravel7}\resources\views\home.blade.php)**

Comment: Es un array, y no un objeto. Usa la sintaxis correspondiente https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing

Answer (score 1):

Comentarios:

1. Este problema esta mas relacionado a PHP que a Laravel
2. Para que tu código sea enteramente funcional, primero deberías corregir el segundo array por que no es de [tipo asociativo](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax) quedando de esta forma:

   ```
   [['nombre' => 'carlos'],['nombre' => 'ana']];
   ```
3. Si hacemos un [`gettype`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.gettype.php) para conocer el tipo de dato

   ```
   $portafolios = [['nombre' => 'carlos'],['nombre' => 'ana']];

   var_dump(gettype($portafolios[0]));
   ```

Veremos lo siguiente:

> string(5) "array"

Dado eso entonces la sintaxis que propones usar de:

```
$alias->clave
```

No resultará pues esto no es un objeto sino un array

4. Si lo que quieres es poder utilizar dicha sintaxis, entonces deberás hacer un [*cast* de valores](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) para que los arrays se *puedan entender como objetos* de la siguiente manera:

   ```
   $portafolios = [(object)['nombre' => 'carlos'],['nombre' => 'ana']];

   var_dump(gettype($portafolios[0]));
   ```

Lo cual nos dará la siguiente salida:

> string(6) "object"

Nota que este *cast* se debe aplicar a ambos arrays internos

**Ejemplo completo**

```
$portafolios = [(object)['nombre' => 'carlos'],(object)['nombre' => 'ana']];

foreach($portafolios as $portafolio) {
    echo $portafolio->nombre.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Nos resultaría lo siguiente:

> carlos 
>  ana